# get filesystem mount point in kernel module

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to get the filesystem mount point for a file system in my kernel module, which is a stackable filesystem.
Eg. if /home/ab/abc is a file and /home is mounted on a different filesystem I want to have a dentry or path struct to /home. 
I want to do this in a module without modifying kernel code.
e.g. there is a file in /home/user/ and now I want to know in which partition this file is. For example this file might be in the partition same as "/" or this file might be in another partition mounted on /home or /home/user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the list of file systems from `current->namespace`. By iterating `current->namespace->list` (items being `struct vfsmount`) you can get all mounted file systems. `vfsmount->mnt_mountpoint` is the directory entry you want.

You can follow the code that `prints /proc/mounts` (e.g. `base.c/mountstats_open`, `namespace.c/m_start`) to get more details (e.g. some locking is needed).

I don't know if you can do it in a kernel module, however.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I wanted to know how to know the mountpoint of a particular file. I have edited the question please if you could take a look at it.

Comment: @gaurav please realize that there could be multiple mount points for any given inode.

Answer (score 1):

If someone still needs to "dereference" given path to its mount point there is [follow_up](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/namei.c#L1183) function which does exactly this thing :) It operates on the *struct path* and changes it accordingly to its *.mnt* entry. Maybe someone will find it handy!

Edit: I've used it in the 5.6 kernel version. I don't know if it was always available (<5.6)

Comment: can you please elaborate how to get mount point of a given path?