# get linux file system information via kernel function

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel-module

I have to write a **linux module** and I can't find a proper function to **list all mounted file system** and their information. I know command "df -T"  can achieve this and sadly I can't use that. Is there a **kernel function** that can do this or other way?

Comment: Have you look [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/df.c;hb=HEAD) ?

Comment: you might use system( "df -T > tempfile;")'; FILE * fp = fopen( tempfile, "r"); fgets(.....

Answer (score 1):

Why not see the kernel code which fills `/proc/mounts`

`mountstats_open()` in `base.c`

refer [get filesystem mount point in kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702261/get-filesystem-mount-point-in-kernel-module)

Comment: I saw the code but can't really understand the usage of "current" in your link that is the macro of "thread_info"? I can't use current->namespace in code.

Comment: @Hao: You do need to somehow decide which filesystem namespace you will query, because the list of mounted filesystems is different for each namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Your code could open/read the `/proc/mounts` file, line by line. It contains everything that is mounted, including many mount points that you would not expect.

In general, the format is the same as the `/etc/fstab` file, but will also include all the mounts that the OS adds.