# Get all mount points in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to get all the mount points in a kernel module. Below is what I've come up with. It segfaults because of the strcat. Is this the correct way to get the mount points? Will this work? if so how do i fix the segfault? If not, how does one go about getting the mount points in a linux kernel module?

I've tried [cycle the whole namespace looking for mountpoint roots that match](http://copilotco.com/mail-archives/security-module.2003/msg00627.html) but its from 2003 and the kernel has changed so much so its basically useless. Also tried [get filesystem mount point in kernel module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702906/6014330) but again its from 2012 so it to is outdated.

```
static int __init misc_init(void)
{
    struct path path;
    struct dentry *thedentry;
    struct dentry *curdentry;

    kern_path("/", LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path);
    thedentry = path.dentry;
    list_for_each_entry(curdentry, &thedentry->d_subdirs, d_child)
    {
        kern_path(strncat("/", curdentry->d_name.name, strlen(curdentry->d_name.name)), LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path);
        if (path_is_mountpoint(&path))
        {
            printk("%s: is a mountpoint", curdentry->d_name.name);
        }
        else
            printk("%s: is not a mountpoint", curdentry->d_name.name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you ever read `man strncat`? You will be surprised.

Comment: yes I have. Ive tried strjoin, strlcat, strncat, strcat.

Comment: ... and the `strlen(curdentry->d_name.name)),` makes no sense at all, either

Comment: So do you understand what is wrong with your `strncat`? Hint: What should be the first parameter?

Comment: fixed that still broke though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are flags for it in the dentry struct. d_flags. and there is a flag DCACHED_MOUNTED. Get the current pointer. The fs_struct in there. then the root. this gives you the root of the current filesystem. from there loop though all the subdirs and if d_flags & DCACHE_MOUNTED passes then it is a mount point.

```
ssize_t read_proc(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t len, loff_t *offp )
{
    struct dentry *curdentry;

    list_for_each_entry(curdentry, &current->fs->root.mnt->mnt_root->d_subdirs, d_child)
    {
        if ( curdentry->d_flags & DCACHE_MOUNTED)
            printk("%s is mounted", curdentry->d_name.name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have used this to list all entries of a given dentry, its only printing one name but there are at least 4 (excluding . and .. ) do  you know whats wrong?

Comment: If you copy pasted the code then it will only print directory names that are mounted, take out the if and just print curdentry->d_name.name if you want all the directories

Answer (score 1):

May be the following is more optimal way to get all mountpoints w/o checking all dentries of a system.

```
struct mnt_namespace *ns = current->nsproxy->mnt_ns;
struct mount *mnt;

list_for_each_entry(mnt, &ns->list, mnt_list) {
...do something with each mnt...
}
```

Note this code doesn't hold `namespace_sem` so the result of iterating thru mnt_list is not guarantee. However, IMHO it is as minimum not less correct than traversing all dentries w/o holding mount lock.