# List all mount points in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module, mount-point

I'm trying to list all the mount points in a kernel module. The method in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46605673/9195380) doesn't list all the mount point, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8702906/9195380) is for older kernel version.
I'm working on kernel version 4.15.0.

I found this method ([iterate_mounts](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/namespace.c#L1870)) and wrote this simple kernel module.

```
int mount_f(struct vfsmount *mnt, void *arg)
{
  char *tmp, *path;
  if(mnt == NULL || mnt->mnt_root == NULL)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  tmp = (char*)__get_free_page(GFP_KERNEL);
  path = dentry_path_raw(mnt->mnt_root, tmp, PAGE_SIZE);
  if(!IS_ERR(path))
  {
    pr_info("mounted path=%s\n", path);
  }
  free_page((unsigned long)tmp);
  return 0;
}

int init_module(void)
{
  struct path path;
  struct vfsmount *root_mnt;
  int err;
  err = kern_path("/", 0, &path);
  if (err)
  {
    return -1;
  }

  root_mnt = path.mnt;
  path_put(&path);
  if (IS_ERR(root_mnt))
  {
    return -1;
  }

  iterate_mounts(mount_f, NULL, root_mnt);
  return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't print the correct path (it prints just "/" for all mounts).
Am I missing something here?

Also, which methods gets called when a new mount is mounted or unmounted?
I'm assuming for unmounting ([do_umount](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/fs/namespace.c#L1529)) gets called?

Edit: another question, how can I identify the mount if it's removable or not? any flags in the `struct vfsmount` or `struct super_block` that can help me identify that?

Comment: The mount folder is a property of upper file system, you are trying to get it from the lower one in the stack. It will be always `/` (maybe with exceptions for some special cases like overlayfs).

Comment: @0andriy Any hint on how to get the upper file system of the mounts?